# How to perform additional actions on PasswordReset in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm using django-axes for the locking of account when a user tries to enter credentials that are not recognized by the system, it will lock the account.

But when I do perform the password reset function using django auth package on a locked account, obviously there is no shortcut way to remove the lock of the account.

Even if the password is already reset, the account will still be locked by django-axes for a couple of minutes.

I'm trying to perform

```
python manage.py axes_reset_username
```

on the **class PasswordResetCompleteView** but I'm not sure how to access the username whose password was reset.

Comment: never used the system, but you can inspect the code https://github.com/jazzband/django-axes/blob/master/axes/utils.py hope it help you.

Answer (score 1):

the auth class had to be overriden to add instructions on password reset. 
here's the code

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from axes.utils import reset

class PasswordResetConfirmView(auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('user_management:password_reset_complete')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        reset(username=user.username)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I did override the form_valid function of class PasswordResetConfirmView. then using django-axes utility to reset **reset(username=user.username)**

hope this helps someone

Comment: helped to debug my function thanks! just FYI for whoever I was passing user object direct to reset() instead of extracting username from it was getting TypeError with not iterable.